# how to use props in react native StyleSheet

Tags: react-native

hello i want to add dark mode in my application so when user change the mode the mode is updated in redux and then i will get colors object for the the current mode

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  var colors = getThemeColors(state.theme);

  return {colors: colors};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

so now i want to get this color props in stylesheet

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: this.props.color.backgroundColor,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
<View style={styles.container("red"} />

...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: bgColor => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: I also try this way but there are many styles
so if it possible to use the state of props in the stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to export your stylesheet as a functional component. So this should look something like this:
Your style.js file :

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const getStyleObj = ({ colors }) => {
 return StyleSheet.create({
  
  textStyle: {
        color: colors.green
    },
};

export default getStyleObj;
```

in Your index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import getStyleObj from "./style";
import {Text} from 'react-native';

const YourComponent = ({ title, ...props }) => {
var colors = getThemeColors(state.theme);
const styles = getStyleObj({colors});

 return (
   <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hello there!</Text
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```